# How to export all emails from a mailbox in Apple Mail

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email

I'm trying to export all emails from an account I have setup and mapped to Apple mail on my computer. There are 1200 emails. The account is no longer active so i'm trying to export all the emails in the mailbox in apple mail to an .mbox file that I can import somewhere else.

The problem is when I do an export of the mailbox and then import it somewhere, there are only 88 emails when there should be 1200+.

Why is this only exporting some of the emails and how can I make it so it exports all of them?

Comment: Export with what, from where, to where?

Comment: Trying to export via the Mail app by selecting a mailbox and going to export mailbox.

I'm then trying to import it into thunderbird for now just to verify that all the emails are there and they're not.

Comment: Where do you see the 1200+, and what it means Account no longer active? (was it a IMAP account)

Comment: It was an IMAP account, and so it downloaded 1200 messages to my computer when i mapped it with IMAP. Now i removed my server where I was hosting the emails so they only exist in my local computer where I mapped it via IMAP. I'm just trying to export them all now to an mbox so I can import them at zoho.com

Comment: As far I know the zoho email does not read (import) the Mac mbox type email files. You would need to convert the mbox to eml type first. There are some free tools to do that, and some that cost money (your choice). The thunderbird should be able to read (IMPORT) the mbox.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to do, but when i import into thunderbird there's only 88 emails...probably due to my export not working from apple mail.

Comment: What are you exporting? just the Inbox or all folders ?

Comment: Look in your Archive folder (all mails) there should be a folder containing all mails for a specific account. Export that one.

Comment: I just want to export the inbox b/c it looks like there is 1200 emails in there. I will try the archive folder.

Comment: Do me a favor, right click on that Inbox and check the size by selecting the Get Account Info.

Comment: Ok the size of the inbox is 2766 messages (i guess the 1200 i was seeing is the unread amount). The size is 131mb. When I right click and do export mailbox is only 3.8mb...how can that be?

Comment: IMAP email is a tricky animal. It actively loads and unloads emails from the server (for example gmail). What you see are the 2766 emails in your web server mail (gmail). The export only exports currently resident emails on your Mac. However there is a folder in Mac mail called Archive. All your emails should be there.

Comment: Do you know where the Archive folder is located? I only see Inbox/Drafts/Outbox/Sent in the apple mail app itself.

Comment: 1) I think the Archive folder that @Buscar웃 is referring to is a Gmail feature, but perhaps you aren't using Gmail? 2) You may be able to open the .mbox file in a text editor and see how many emails it actually contains: that way you can tell if the problem is Mail.app's export, or Thunderbird's import.

Comment: If i open it in a text editor, how can I count them all? By hand? The mbox file is 69766 lines.

Comment: As far as I remember, the each separate message starts the same way, perhaps with a line starting with "From ", or ">From "? TextEdit.app shows a count of the number of matches at the right of the search box when you use the Find feature. It's a little more tricky to get it to match "[start of line]From", but I think you can do this using the "Insert Pattern" menu option (click the magnifying glass at the left of the search box).

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't get my export working even with a mailbox rebuild.  However, my goal was simply to archive my old mail, and not necessarily to do so in the mbox format, so copying the raw mailbox via Terminal with `cp` was adequate for my purposes.

After some trial and error, I found the path was `~/Library/Mail/V3/IMAP-<account-name>/`.  Sharing it here in case anyone else is in the same boat.

Comment: I guess you mean `cp` not `mv`

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that to import those folders into another mac, one should choose Import from: Apple Mail instead of files in mbox format.. The latter would be used for mboxes exported with the export function.

Answer (score 8):

**Solving the annoying** *Some messages could not be imported* - **Error** in Mail.app.

I figured out a pretty easy way to copy all E-Mails from my old MacBook to my new machine with Mail.app.

*(MacOS Mojave 10.14.2; Mail 12.2)*

Don't export your mailboxes as .mbox (Mail.app > Mailbox > Export Mailbox...)

I pretty much always got the following error when I imported the previously exported .mbox files to my new Macbook:

```
Some messages could not be imported. The partially imported mailboxes are located in the mailbox named “Import” in the mailboxes list.
```

The odd thing is that Mail.app doesn't tell you which E-Mails have not been copied.
This uncertainty is very frustrating especially when you want to move thousands of E-Mails.

There is a simple **workaround** using EMLs instead of .mbox:

1. In Finder create a folder for every mailbox you want to copy. In any case you should create a minimum of 2 folders. You’ll see why soon.
2. In Mail.app select one mailbox at a time. Select all mails inside and drag & drop them into the corresponding folder in the finder. The mails are copied into the folder as EML. Note that it might take a very long time before the .eml files appear, but you can check in Activity Monitor if Mail is doing something, it'll be using a significant percent of processor (10%-90% of a core in my case). As a reference, for 10 000 emails, it took over 2 hours until the .eml were exported.
3. On the new machine open Mail.app.
   File > Import Mailboxes… > Import data from Apple Mail
4. Important! Select at least 2 folders to import. If you only select one folder, Mail.app imports every EML file in its own mailbox! (This would work but it takes long to delete the empty mailboxes after you’ve moved all the mails into one mailbox.)

Done!
With this technique I've copied thousands of E-Mails from one Mail.app to another Mail.app without any errors.

Comment: drake, thank you so much for this.  incredibly **THIS IS THE ONLY WAY TO DO IT.**  thanks.

Comment: Note that emails with subject lines of 252 characters or more [will silently fail](https://tinyapps.org/blog/202206140700_mail-app-export.html) to export when using this click-and-drag to Finder method.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was here: https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/macos-mail-archiving-messages/

Basically, click "Options" then check "export all subfolders". My export went from one .mbox at 44kb to several at 5.6GB.

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU!

Comment: Holy shit what a terrible UI blunder by Apple. Thank-you - I have an empty top level folder with MANY subfolders and I was ripping my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first lets get our numbers sorted out.

Select the mail box (Inbox) you are trying to export, then select all messages and use the Mark as Unread.

Now look how many does it shows in that Mail box.

Now the export should export all of them.

Next is to do the Import Mail box to verify. Use the Import Mailboxes in the File menu then select the exported mbox file. The count should be the same as export. Now you can delete the Import mail box that you no longer need.

This is not to be confused with the Inbox on the server (from your email provider), which you can only access true Internet.

Since your account is no longer active you can not get those messages from server anyway until you reactivate it, they might be still there for you to get them. If you deleted the Internet email account then the game is over.

In order to get more clarity, please specify what email provider were you using for that email.

Comment: There is no mark as unread option: http://snag.gy/doRyx.jpg. Account info shows 2766 messages http://snag.gy/ucweJ.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots. First when you use Mark as Read, then go again now it has changed to Mark as Unread, it is a flip flop switch. second, your mail Inbox shows 1199 unread messages- but it also show the warning sign that that Inbox is not online (not connected to the server. When you do the get Account Info, it goes to your ONLINE account and shows you the situation there. You have a warning there saying that account is offline thus the numbers do not match. If you follow my procedure above, to test the export from your Inbox that is in your Mac Mail.

Comment: Please do not confuse the 2 Inbox. One is on your Mac, the other is on the server (Internet connection). You do not have 2766 messages on your Mac mail to export, those are on the server. You would have to get them from the server first.

Comment: Ok after marking all as read then unread, there are 1382 on my local computer

Comment: Thank you, so now the first test is to export all of them then import back in the mail and check the count to verify that the exporting works. Next step would be to test the importing in to Thunderbolt--Zoho.

Comment: So now when i export the mailbox in apple.mail and then import it back into apple.mail there is only 4 emails.

Comment: OK, that Mailbox might be broken. Leave the all Unread (to see the count), create new Mail folder, now select all of them in the original folder and use the copy to a new folder Right click to get the copy to:). Now try the export that new folder (and import to check the count found in the import folder).

Comment: Ok if i create a folder called testing and then select all the emails in the inbox and right click and copy to testing, the testing folder contains only emails and I see this error: http://snag.gy/oo5IP.jpg.

Comment: outch :)  ok last resort. Lets find the emails in your library and try to copy from there. To do that use Finder and go to /Users/your_user_name/Library/Mail/V2 and look for it

Comment: Sorry, lets make it more simple copy following in to the Finders Go to window "~/Library/Mail/V2" then find your mail account. If there is a something.mbox use that one, if not lets talk.

Comment: As you said, before copying the `~/Library/Mail/Vx` folder one should be **sure** that all the emails from the remote account have been downloaded locally (**supposedly** the `Mailbox->Rebuild` command will do that). But copying/pasting just the folder will **not restore** the emails on the new remote account. That in my case is a no go (I want to transfer *everything* to a another account, either locally **and** remotely, given that the email is via IMAP).

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't export the entire mailbox - only 200mb were exported. After I did a Mailbox Rebuild (see `Mailbox > Rebuild` in the Menubar), all mails (1.25GB) were exported.

Answer (score 0):

I have a deactivated email account, which I would like to backup all the emails locally as .mbox, and can be easily further transferred between different email client (i.e. from Mac Mail to Thunderbird etc).

But every time, I select a mailbox --> (right click) Export Mailbox, it only exports around 25 emails out of the total 2000+ emails..

By accident, I found a trick worked for me. One has to select a mailbox folder, and **uses the small settings (gear) icon at the bottom of the panel, to do the export!**
Then you will find it will export all the emails contained in that folder!
This worked for me at least, but it seems it is definitely a bug of the software..

[image: the button]